# mean of the entire dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, mean

I have a dataframe

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(loc.id = rep(1:5, each = 4*2), year = rep(rep(1980:1983,each = 2),times = 5), 
             type = rep(2:3, times = 4*5), x = runif(5*4*2), y = runif(5*4*2), z = runif(5*4*2))
```

If I have to take the mean of col x or col y, I could use `colMeans`

What I want to do is for each loc.id and year:

```
    test <- df[df$loc.id == 1 & df$year == 1980,]

    loc.id  year  type         x         y         z
      1    1980    2     0.6478935 0.5022996 0.2387260
      1    1980    3     0.3198206 0.3539046 0.9623589
```

I want to take the mean, sd and cv of x,y,z which in the above case will be:

```
 mean.eg <- mean(c(test$x,test$y,test$z)) 
 sd.eg <- sd(c(test$x,test$y,test$z)) 
 cv.eg <- sd.eg/mean.eg * 100
```

So that my data looks like

```
loc.id  year   mean.eg sd.eg cv.eg
   1      1980
   1      1981
   1      1983
   2      1980
   2      1981
   2      1983
```

This gives me an error

```
 df %>% group_by(loc.id,year) %>% summarise(mean = c(x,y,z))
```

Comment: You need to use the `mean()` function, just like you did above. `summarise(mean = mean(c(x,y,z)))`. By itself, `c` just concatenates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
> mean(apply(df,1,function(x) mean(x[4:6])))
[1] 0.510727
```